# CustomNaming strategy with mapstruct SPI

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to get mapstruct working on beans with an different setter naming convention. Some of the beans in the project are name like `withValue(string val)`

Based on the documentation it is possible to accomplish implementing AccessorNamingStrategy in the project and configuring the SPI. 
Based on this I created my own NamingStrategy and have the following file created in my project

`/META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AccessorNamingStrategy`
with the fully quaified name of my custom implementation in it.

But I couldn't seem to get the spi working for my custom naming strategy.

Digging in to the Options.java I found the property "`mapstruct.alwaysGenerateServicesFile`" need to be set to true.
But the annotation processor in intelliJ seem to reject this property as not recoganized by any of the annotation processors.

I also see this property "`mapstruct.alwaysGenerateServicesFile`" not documented in http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.1/reference/html/index.html#configuration-options

Is this feature still supported in MapStruct. Did anybody got custom naming strategy working in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I actually got it

Need to package `/META-INF/services/org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AccessorNamingStrategy`

and the 
`CustomNamingStrategy` in a separate jar and include it in the main project.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. The naming strategy SPI is also described in the MapStruct [reference guide](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/index.html#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy) now.